# Get NSTextFieldCell value using AppleScript

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface, cocoa, applescript

I am trying to automate a few tasks where I need to get the text displayed on a dialog box (the 6 digit code).

[image: dialog box]

Accessibility Inspector revealed the following hierarchy:

[image: Accessibility Inspector]

I am a beginner in the field of AppleScript and have read a few examples where something similar could be done like this:

```
set myText to textField's stringValue() as text
```

But I'm not sure if this could work in my case, as the Accessibility Inspector does not show any variable names for `NSTextFieldCell` which contains the 6 digit code.

How can I extract the 6 digit code in the `NSTextFieldCell` and possibly return this value so that a shell script can use this code?

I have something like this right now -

```
tell application "FollowUpUI"
    activate
    # get the 6 digit code
end tell
```

---

**Update**

After some help, i have tried to traverse to the text field

```
tell application "System Events"

    repeat with theProcess in processes

        #initialize
        tell theProcess
            set processName to name
            set allWindows to windows
        end tell

        #check if process exists
        if processName is "FollowUpUI" then

            activate

            say "FollowUpUI found"

            set windowsCount to count of the allWindows

            #only one window should exist
            if windowsCount is 1 then
                say "1 window was found"

                tell window 1
                    tell group 1
                        tell text field 1
                            set code to value
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell

            end if
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

but i've got stuck because of an error -

```
System Events got an error: cant get window 1. Invalid index.
```

I am not sure if this is a syntax error. Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: You have to use (ugly) GUI scripting with `System Events` in AppleScript. You cannot access UI elements of other applications / processes with Cocoa.

Comment: Can you please point me to the right direction, perhaps an example? I wont mind an ugly solution.

Comment: You have to `tell application "System Events" to tell process "[name of process]" to tell window [1] to tell group 1 to tell text field 1 to set theValue to its value`. All values in `[]` are arbitrary and in real code without the brackets.

Comment: If i am getting this correctly, this might involve a bit of "hit and trial". How do i find the right values to put in the `[]`. Could i print out the `windows` or `groups` to find the right values? Apologies, i am very new to this.

Comment: It's a bit less annoying than *hit and trial*. First you need to get the name of the process. The name of the application seems to be `FollowUpUI`, so compare the name to the result of `tell application "System Events" to get name of processes`. It's most likely window 1 (unless there is another invisible window). **You have to use `System Events`, you cannot access the application directly**, it's certainly not scriptable.

Comment: Hi @vadian, i have updated my question. I still cant traverse to the text field and it looks like i somehow have the incorrect syntax. Any pointers would be helpful, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you have to reference `window 1 of process "FollowUpUI"`

Your code is too complicated, you just need to check if the process exists

```
tell application "System Events"
    if exists process "FollowUpUI" then
        tell process "FollowUpUI"
            tell window 1
                tell static text 1 of group 1
                    set code to its value
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

If the code is a part of a workflow you have to wait until the window is open

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists window 1 of process "FollowUpUI"
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
    tell window 1 of process "FollowUpUI"
        tell static text 1 of group 1
            set code to its value
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

I added `its` before `value` to make sure that it refers to the current reference (the text field)

As you don't send key or mouse events to the window you don't need to `activate` anything.

Comment: Thanks @vadian, I am testing with the dialog open. Both of these snippets still throw the same error - `System Events got an error: Cant get text field 1 of group 1 of window 1 of process "FollowUpUI". Invalid Index`. I have put up a `say "found"` statement after tell process statement to check if the process exists. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Then the reference is wrong. You can use a tool like `UI Browser` (not free but it might have a trial period) or an editor like `Script Debugger` (not free either) which has an property inspector. Or you have to `log` the `UI elements` from the root (the process) to the destination (the text field) while the affected window is open to figure out the reference chain.

Comment: PS: I suspect it's not a **text field**, it's something else – as `...Cell` reveals

Comment: Yes its not a text field. The Accessibility Inspector calls it `NSTextFieldCell`. Does `applescript` support `NSTextField`? Also if i were to use `Script Debugger` or similar tools would they show a different hierarchy from the Accessibility Inspector?

Comment: For example `UI Browser` can provide the actual AppleScript code for the selected reference. Both mentioned tools can give more information about the UI element like the class and the attributes.

Comment: `UI Browser` helped me fix it! The text box was called `static text 1`. Thanks a lot @vadian! Please update your answer so i can mark it, I owe you one :)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but I can't paste code in a comment. Here's a trick to get the UI Element. Hit Command-Shift-4 to get a cursor with coordinates. Aim at the UI Element and remember the coordinates. Click to get the arrow cursor back. Use the coordinates in this script.

```
activate application "FollowUpUI"
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "FollowUpUI"
        click at {290, 150}
    end tell
end tell
```

Script Editor must be allowed to control the computer. You can set this in the System prefs, Security & Privacy, Privacy.

Comment: I need to extract the 6 digit code before i hit the Done key.